# Uninstalling hello-again App from elementary OS developer tutorial

Tags: development

I went through the Getting Started documentation this evening and successfully installed my hello-again App into my Applications menu. Now I'm trying to figure out how to uninstall it and having no luck. Typing "hello-again" into the Terminal opens it fine, but

sudo apt-get purge hello-again

gives me an error:

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hello-again"

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you build and install a package as well?

If not, I guess you just did `make install`. In this case you will have to remove the files installed manually

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/hello-again
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/hello.desktop
```